# Defining magnetic flux in rotating cylinder

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

Suppose We have a charged rotating cylinder such that the magnetic field inside it is the same as a solenoid of the exact same dimensions. Obviously, the current per-unit length for both will be the same.

Now, what can we say about the magnetic flux in the cylinder since there is no n (turns per unit length)?
What can we comment about inductance? It depends on n and not current.

Comment: Cab you give the charge on the cylinder to achieve the same current? Why nor spin a  charged coil first coil ? and discuss the charge needed

Comment: The charge density and angular velocity will determine the current. You are free to choose any value and match the field with a solenoid of same dimensions